# Swift Application URL Handler

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am trying to determine from which application did my application get launched. I have created the app to handle http(s) requests and registered a URL handler within the applicationWillFinishLaunching.  This is all working as expected. Within the event handler the first parameter is an Apple Event Descriptor, which has 2 items. The first is the URL that was clicked on. The second item is also an Apple Event Descriptor and it contains a data structure with the name and the identifier of the previous application.

For example, if I was in Mail and clicked on a URL. The URL is in the first Event Descriptor. When converted to a string, the second descriptor contains a bundle identifier and agent name in a dictionary.

Is there a way to parse the second event data structure to retrieve the information?

Comment: you should provide some code of what you have tried. otherwise you'll receive downvotes soon

Comment: At least you should add the content of the descriptor to your Q.